# Doctrine convert-mapping except a table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I wish to convert all tables in my database to a Doctrine mapping, except one table. How do I do that through CLI?

From what I understand you can add --filter option but for the best of me I cannot figure out how to filter the table.

Here is what I had so far (does not work, i_dont_want_this table still being included):

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --filter="^(?!(i_dont_want_this)$)" --from-database php App/Models
```

Comment: in your filter you have to give a string pattern used to match entities that should be processed. Thats in the Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command line 57.Check the docs again